# Verify Nimbus JOSE+JWT token (Java) in nodejs?

Tags: android, node.js, jwt

I want to verify the Json Web Token, which is generated using Nimbus Jose package. I am using SECP256K1 keypairs for signing and verification. My ECPrivateKey look like this

```
EC Private Key
     S: 69d26ca7bd25017c0e00d9cb78fbb368f7f3b4fdb2d2254aeeb7fa4d4a6cd36a
```

And my token is `eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NksifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoiU2FuamF5IFBhdGVsIiwiZW1haWwiOiJzYW5qYXlAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NTU1ODUzNjJ9.0b1pQ2-ru7e8UTgAo1mPJaND92xm-k3sHcHQxjoGnrrczPz369rBBKWj7m0dy6_7XSO2nC-VjF03ORKzmgqX-Q`

Now I want to verify this token in Nodejs using the publicKey format

```
0xf65416848e73bdf6bb90554e0ed2f89e95b6b2fdbc502b0a2ecf9164de4ea4f7fdce4d58c93795bf0b4c733162206710f3cbbd3244751355f5389b9317c6d3e7
```

I am deriving this key from ECPublicKey

```
EC Public Key
   X: f65416848e73bdf6bb90554e0ed2f89e95b6b2fdbc502b0a2ecf9164de4ea4f7
   Y: fdce4d58c93795bf0b4c733162206710f3cbbd3244751355f5389b9317c6d3e7
```

Suggest me the suitable node Module for this kind of verification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jwt-js node module does the things for me.